# PHPUnit / Selenium 2 randomly failing on ajax-heavy webapp

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver, phpunit

My selenium tests are failing with a PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_NoSeleniumException exception. But not not always, and not always on the same element.

I suspect this has got to do with the speed of execution, i.e. the element is not yet visible when selector is executed.

I have searched SO, but find mostly either Java-related suggestions involving WebdriverWait (not in PHPUnit/Selenium as far as I could find) or deal with the older Selenium RC commands like waitForPageLoad etc.

How do I make these tests more stable? Should I wrap the selection of elements in a function that tries repeatedly (for a certain amount of iteration) to select the element, using sleep() between iterations? What is common/best practice for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the problem. My initial thoughts, that selenium needs more time to locate the elements, seems incorrect. The selenium server spends some time doing "Executing: [find element:...", but then follows up immediately with "Executing: [delete session:...".

So that explains why sleep() or anything like that didnt help my test.

Googling some more, I found this [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/selenium-users/ETVMk3mcI6Q).
So it seems that my current Selenium Server, 2.26.0, doesnt work nice with my FF 17.0. I verified by installing the ChromeDriver and running my tests repeatedly on Chrome, which passed every time.

So now i can either:

1. Try and compile latest sources for a sort-of-bleeding-edge Selenium
   and see if it works against FF17
2. Downgrade FF to 16.0 or lower
3. Use Chrome (and IE, and Opera, etc) for my tests till 2.27.0 arrives

I dont really want to downgrade, so for now i'll take option 3 and run my tests against Chrome. This is just the initial setup of functional testing for me anyway, so expanding the tests to multiple browsers can be done later on.

**Edit:** now using FireFox again with Selenium 2.27.0